# passing image and displaying it

Tags: ios, swift3

So after studying, researching and outsoursing i couldnt figure my problem out :(. I am currently trying to get used to segue for view to view while passing values. So whats better then developing a simple app?

My app is like this... first page with one image array that randomly spits out an image when the view loads and one action buttonthat triggers the view segue to the next view using segue preform function.

the second page contains a dismiss button and an image view that should change depend on the randomly passed image from the previeous view image array.

Everything works fine except that I cannot see the randomly passed image.

Below is my code:

Page 1

```
import UIKit

class MainWelcomVC: UIViewController {



var ImageArr = [UIImageView]()

@IBOutlet weak var BackGround: UIImageView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for x in 0...2 {

        let image = UIImage(named: "char\(x).png")
        let imageview = (UIImageView(image: image))
        ImageArr.append(imageview)

    }


}

@IBAction func PlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ImageArr.count)))
    let CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CharDisplayVC", sender: CharImage)

}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? CharDisplayVC{

        if let ImageFinal = sender as? UIImage {
            destination.ImageToDisplay = ImageFinal
        }
}


}
}
```

page2

```
import UIKit

class CharDisplayVC: UIViewController {

private var _ImageToDisplay: UIImage!

var ImageToDisplay: UIImage {

    get {

        return _ImageToDisplay

    } set {

        _ImageToDisplay = newValue
    }

}


@IBOutlet weak var CharPicture: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CharPicture.image = _ImageToDisplay


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func PlayAgainBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found a solution after fooling around and it was to make everything a UIimage object including the array, below is the new code for  page 1:

```
import UIKit

class MainWelcomVC: UIViewController {

var ImageArr = [UIImage]()
var CharImage: UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var BackGround: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for x in 0...2 {

        let image = UIImage(named: "char\(x).png")
        ImageArr.append(image!)
    }
}




@IBAction func PlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ImageArr.count)))
    self.CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex]

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CharDisplayVC", sender: self)
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if let destination = segue.destination as? CharDisplayVC {

        if let ImageFinal = self.CharImage as? UIImage! {
            destination.ImageToDisplay = ImageFinal
        }
   }
  }
 }
```

I still have a yellow warning which says "Conditional cast from 'UIImage?' to 'UIImage!' always succeeds" and another one which says "Pattern match introduces an implicit promotion from 'UIImage!' to 'UIImage!?'" in the below code:

```
  if let ImageFinal = self.CharImage as? UIImage! {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how I use the `sender` parameter in segues. Generally I call `self` since the UIViewController is making the `performSegue` call. Something like the following should work.

```
import UIKit

class MainWelcomVC: UIViewController {

    var ImageArr = [UIImageView]()
    var CharImage: UIImage?

    @IBOutlet weak var BackGround: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for x in 0...2 {

            let image = UIImage(named: "char\(x).png")
            let imageview = (UIImageView(image: image))
            ImageArr.append(imageview)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PlayButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ImageArr.count)))
        self.CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex].image

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CharDisplayVC", sender: self)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let destination = segue.destination as? CharDisplayVC {

            if let ImageFinal = self.CharImage as? UIImage {
                destination.ImageToDisplay = ImageFinal
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still giving me a problem of cannot assign UIImage to UIImage view in 

       CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex]

and 

      if let ImageFinal = CharImage as? UIImage

Comment: I updated `self.CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex]` to `self.CharImage = ImageArr[randomIndex].image`. My apologies on missing that. It should work now.

Comment: yes thanx this worked too but i have manged to get it to work by changing the array and couple of other lines. can you check the code in my answer below and tell me if it is a good way to do it? also i cant figure the diffirance between UI Image view and UIimage

Comment: Your updated code is also a good way to achieve the desired functionality. A `UIImage` is a data object that holds reference to an image file. A `UIImageView` is a user interface object responsible for rendering a `UIImage`. A `UIImageView` can be used in `Storyboards` where a `UIImage` cannot. Does that help differentiate?

Comment: yes it makes sense now @Dehaan Solo , but can I use both together or should I use UIimage and when should I use UIimageview?

Comment: I generally use both together like this `let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "my-image"))`.